# R error when using untar

Tags: r, tar

I'm running a script with input parameters that are referenced in the code to automate the directory creation, download of file and `untar` of file. I would be fine with `unzip`, however this particular file I want to analyze is `.tar.gz`.  I manually unpacked and it was tar.gz, unpacked to .tar file.  Would that be the problem?

> ```
> Full error: Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) : unsupported entry type ‘’
> ```

Running Windows 10, 64 bit, R set to: `[Default] [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2`

Script notes one solution found (issues, lines 28-31), but I don't really understand it.

I did install 7-zip on my computer, restart and of course restart R:

```
`#DOWNLOADING AND UNZIPPING TAR FILE

#load required packages.  
#If there is a load package error, use install.packages("[package]")
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(XML) # HTML processing
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Set directory locations, data file and fetch data file from internet
#enter full url including file name between ' ' marks
mainDir<-"C:/R/BEES/"
subDir<-"C:/R/BEES/Killers"
Fetch<-'http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/nationalatlas/afrbeep020_nt00218.tar.gz'
ArchFile<-basename(Fetch)
download.file<-(ArchFile)

#Check for file directories and create if directory if it doesn't exist
if(!file.exists(mainDir)){dir.create(mainDir)} 
if(!file.exists(subDir)){dir.create(subDir)} 

#set the working directory
setwd(file.path(subDir))

#check if file exists and download if it doesn't exist.
if(!file.exists(ArchFile))
{download.file (url=Fetch,destfile=ArchFile,method='auto')}


#unpack and view file list
untar(path.expand(ArchFile),list=TRUE,exdir=subDir,compressed="gzip")
list.files(subDir)

#Error: Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) : 
# unsupported entry type ‘’
#Need solution to use tar/untar app
#instructions here: https://stevemosher.wordpress.com/step-10-build/`
```

Appreciate feedback - I've been lurking around StackOverflow for some time to use other people's solutions.

Comment: Sometimes just asking for help helps...  Issue resolved with:
untar(path.expand("~/ArchFile"),list=TRUE,exdir=subDir,compressed="gzip")

Comment: It's a nice practice to answer your own question, just post it as an answer for future visitors (and not as a comment).

Comment: Thank you, will do in the future.